# React app freezes when building in Lightsail

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, amazon-lightsail, react-scripts

I'm trying to build my react app with this script `react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build` however it freezes on `Creating an optimized production build...`

I've tried removing the `--max_old_space_size` flag however I get this error:

`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Could someone point me into the right direction to solve this issue.

Thanks